# How to pass a local variable to the next function with a return statement in Python

Tags: python, function, return, local-variables

I am new to Python, and have been frustrated with trying to pass variables to a subsequent function, at the most basic level.  I've researched on this and other sites, but not getting a clear answer that would fit.  I don't want to use a global variables.  I've tried all manner of Positional Arguments to the functions based on IDLE's error reports, but I just can't understand why, in the following code, the first two functions work as desired, but the third, which follows the exact same structure, fails.  here's the code:

```
#passing values between functs.

def func1():
    initial_value = 'abc'
    print(initial_value, "is the initial value.")
    value_to_pass = initial_value
    return value_to_pass

def func2(value_to_pass):
    print("\nIn FUNC2 now. Did the value pass?")
    print(value_to_pass, "is the passed value.")
    new_value1 = value_to_pass + 'd'
    print(new_value1, "is the new value.")
    return new_value1

def func3(new_value1):
    print("\nIn FUNC3 now. Did the value pass?")
    print(new_value1, "is the passed value.")
    new_value2 = new_value1 + 'e'
    print(new_value2, "is the new value.")


#main
func2(func1())
func3(func2())


input("\nPress the ENTER key to EXIT.")
```

I've tried adding in `value_to_pass` as a parameter to the `func3` call of `func2` under `#main`, as the IDLE error suggests, and other combinations of things to try to get it to work, but no luck. Can someone please explain to me why and what is going wrong here?

Comment: This question does not belong on SO. Even if some other newbie were to have a similar question, they'd never be able to locate this discussion. Try e.g. finding a local python meetup to help you out with your learning.

Answer (score 1):

func2 expects an argument. try

```
#main
func2(func1())
func3(func2(func1()))
```

or

```
#main
func2(func1())
func3(func2('e'))
```

By the way, if you are writing about error messages, please post your stack trace. It'll make it a lot easier to examine your problem.

Comment: OUTPUT:abc is the intial value.

In FUNC2 now. Did the value pass?
abc is the passed value.
abcd is the new value.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users....pass_vals_prog.py", line 25, in <module>
    func3(func2())
TypeError: func2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value_to_pass'

Comment: #main
func2(func1())
func3(func2(func1()))

Answer (score 0):

In the code `func2(func1())` you're using the `return` from `func1` as the variable required in the `func2` definition. With your examples, `func1` will always satisfy the requirements of passing a variable to `func2` or `func3`

Remember, `func2` and `func3` must always have a variable inside the ()s.  That variable *can* be a returned value from calling another function such as `func2(func1())`, but it cannot be blank, like in your second example `func3(func2())`.

In the second example `func3` variable requirement is satisfied by the return value of `func2`, but `func2` is not getting a variable passed, so it's failing. As previously mentioned, you will need to put something inside the `func2()` part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

@jim:
Thanks this worked:

```
#main
func2(func1())
func3(func2(func1()))
```

abc is the intial value.

In FUNC2 now. Did the value pass?
abc is the passed value.
abcd is the new value.
abc is the intial value.

In FUNC2 now. Did the value pass?
abc is the passed value.
abcd is the new value.

In FUNC3 now. Did the value pass?
abcd is the passed value.
abcde is the new value.

Press the ENTER key to EXIT.